# Preview won't remember the last viewed page of PDF

Tags: pdf, preview

When I open a PDF file that was viewed days ago, Preview will open the first page.

However, when I close it and open it again right now, it will open the right (last viewed) page.

The option `Start on the last viewed page` was checked.

Comment: Can you (as user) and/or Preview.app write to the directory where your document resides?

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes, I can edit the PDF file with Preview and save it in place.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade from Yosemite to El Captain could mess up the preference files.
Delete the folder **/Users/{user name}/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview** to reset settings.